# How can I read an XML file and store into a OODBMSs (Siaqodb) with LinQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-entities, object-oriented-database

XMl-ODBMSs noob here, so I was trying to find out the most efficient way to read an xml file and store it as data objects on my Siaqodb. I've been looking for tutorial and its been hard to find any. If anybody could help me out with, I'd be greatful.

```
<MusicList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Music>
        <Album>Atabales Mix</Album>
        <AlbumArtist>Desconocido</AlbumArtist>
        <AlbumCover>http://192.168.100.5:9000/rpc/cat/IVANS/Covers/Grupo De Palos - Atabales Mix.jpg</AlbumCover>
        <Artist>Grupo De Palos</Artist>
        <ArtistCover>http://192.168.100.5:9000/rpc/cat/IVANS/Covers/Grupo De Palos_300_300.jpg</ArtistCover>
        <Genre>Atabal</Genre>
        <GenreCover>http://192.168.100.5:9000/rpc/cat/IVANS/Covers/Atabal_300_300.jpg</GenreCover>
        <Path>http://192.168.100.5:9000/rpc/cat/IVANS/Music/Atabal/GRUPO DE PALO BANI - TRACK 04.MP3</Path>
        <Title>Dolores</Title>
    </Music>
    <Music>
        <Album>Atabales Mix</Album>
        <AlbumArtist>Desconocido</AlbumArtist>
        <AlbumCover>http://192.168.100.5:9000/rpc/cat/IVANS/Covers/Grupo De Palos - Atabales Mix.jpg</AlbumCover>
        <Artist>Grupo De Palos</Artist>
        <ArtistCover>http://192.168.100.5:9000/rpc/cat/IVANS/Covers/Grupo De Palos_300_300.jpg</ArtistCover>
        <Genre>Atabal</Genre>
        <GenreCover>http://192.168.100.5:9000/rpc/cat/IVANS/Covers/Atabal_300_300.jpg</GenreCover>
        <Path>http://192.168.100.5:9000/rpc/cat/IVANS/Music/Atabal/GRUPO DE PALO BANI - TRACK 01.MP3</Path>
        <Title>Espiritu divino</Title>
    </Music>
</MusicList>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can easily read the xml file using DataSet ReadXml method.  You can the create a connection to your database and a command.   The command has 4 method : Select, Update, Insert, and Delete.  You can save the DataSet using the Update or Insert Methods.

Comment: This is very general, please show some examples. What have you tried?

Comment: I resolved the problem by using the .Load() method to load the file using the XDocument object from LinQ to XML package, loading each element from the xml file and iterating a foreach loop with a counter variable to break it on 100 objects, then stored them into the database, and voila!.

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved the problem by using the XDocument method .Load(), calling the elements of the object and iterating a foreach loop with a condition inside. Then, I stored those objects into the database.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Canciones
        {
            public string Album { get; set; }
            public string AlbumArtist { get; set; }
            public string AlbumCover { get; set; }
            public string Artist { get; set; }
            public string ArtistCover { get; set; }
            public string Genre { get; set; }
            public string GenreCover { get; set; }
            public string Path { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public int OID { get; set; }
        }
       public static void Main()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            Siaqodb siaqodb = new Siaqodb(@"d:\Siaqodb\database\TEST\");

           List<Canciones> musicList = (from m in XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\ivan_000\Desktop\MusicList.xml")
                                           .Descendants("Music")
                                           select new Canciones{
                                           Album = m.Element("Album").Value,
                                           AlbumArtist = m.Element("AlbumArtist").Value,
                                           AlbumCover = m.Element("AlbumCover").Value,
                                           Artist = m.Element("Artist").Value,
                                           ArtistCover = m.Element("ArtistCover").Value,
                                           Genre = m.Element("Genre").Value,
                                           GenreCover = m.Element("GenreCover").Value,
                                           Path = m.Element("Path").Value,
                                           Title = m.Element("Title").Value,
                                           OID = musicList.Count()                                          

                                           }).ToList();

                        foreach(Cancion cancion in musicList)
                        {
                            counter++;
                            if (counter <= 100)
                                    siaqodb.StoreObject(cancion);   
                            else
                                break;                  
                        }

        }

    }
```